# Differentiating between Different Users Logging in With the Same SSH Credentials

Tags: ssh

The development environment in my company is current... a little weird, and I've been wondering if I can alleviate some of the weirdness. Currently, we log into a (jump) host A (with our own unique credentials), from where we SSH into the the development boxes (with a shared account). A big downside to this, obviously, is that we don't really have any customization - any changes to the environment would affect everyone. So I was wondering if there is a way to, once we are on a given dev box, inspect... some piece of metadata about the SSH connection and run different init scripts?

Comment: Can the `sshd_config`s on the dev boxes be easily modified? You could send an env var containing the user name over from Host A using `SendVar`/`AcceptVar` in the ssh_config/sshd_config.

Comment: Can't do that myself, but I can check in with the team in charge of those machines.